# How to display HTML document in JavaFX WebView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

I have created a webview and I am trying to load an html document from my local machine, located in the project src folder. But when I try and load it nothing happens, I also tried loading it as content. Any ideas on why this is and how to fix it.

```
    final WebView wv = new WebView();
    final WebEngine we = wv.getEngine();
    we.load("test.html");
```

Comment: Did you test https://google.com as url of your webview ?

Comment: The `load(...)` method is expecting the String form of a URL. To load something from your filesystem you need something like `we.load(Paths.get("test.html").toUri().toString());`. If that doesn't work, you can at least log the value of `Paths.get("test.html").toUri().toString()` and see if it makes sense (i.e. points to a valid location in your file system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this

```
 File f = new File("C:\\Users\\User_Name\\Desktop\\test.html");
    try {
        webView.getEngine().load(f.toURI().toURL().toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestWeb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```